# Print a better layered cake

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, unicode

I was looking at my previous challenge and thought I could make a better version, but I didn't want to modify that one, so here it is!

---

### Challenge

Given an input `n`,

- print an ASCII art cake `n` layers tall,
- viewed from the side,
- with two candles on top,
- using box drawing characters.
- First layer is thinner than the others.
- Refer to the examples below.

### Example output

```
>> cake(1)
╭─╨─╨─╮
└─────┘

>> cake(2)
  ╭─╨─╨─╮
╭─┴─────┴─╮
│         │
└─────────┘

>> cake(3)
    ╭─╨─╨─╮
  ╭─┴─────┴─╮
  │         │
╭─┴─────────┴─╮
│             │
└─────────────┘

>> cake(4)
      ╭─╨─╨─╮
    ╭─┴─────┴─╮
    │         │
  ╭─┴─────────┴─╮
  │             │
╭─┴─────────────┴─╮
│                 │
└─────────────────┘
```

...and so on.

### Rules

- Standard loopholes prohibited
- Please make an attempt at a clever solution
- Since multi-byte box drawing characters are used, solution size is measured in characters, not bytes. (Compiled/binary sizes are still measured in bytes, however.)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in characters wins. However, the answer will not be selected.

### Have fun!

Comment: I will be happy if someone gives me an answer in silos. This seems doable. https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala seems like a nice language, great job!

Comment: @DJMcMayhem are you accusing me of _ripping off my own challenge?_

Comment: I'm not accusing you of ripping anything off. I just don't see the point of having two different challenges with an almost identical goal, and since ["Answers from one question could be copied over to the other with little or no modification and still be competitive"](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1876/31716), I voted to closed.

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev thanks

Comment: @DJMcMayhem You now have to properly join the cake layers instead of just printing them out sequentially, then adding a bottom layer. Many strategies used in the original code golf would not work.

Comment: Besides being a duplicate, I think this the other version is more interesting. Though this cake is prettier, the bottom being distinct from others and the "┴" characters limits reuse of parts of the string, limiting the optimizations you can make and pushing more towards printing the individual parts.